# function findOne that takes an array and query as input and finds an object in the array that contains the query

Tags: javascript

I have to write a function that searches through an array of objects for a query and returns the first object that matches the query.
For example the array will look something like this:

```
 const HEROES = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Captain America', squad: 'Avengers' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Iron Man', squad: 'Avengers' },
{ id: 3, name: 'Spiderman', squad: 'Avengers' },
 ];
```

the call to the function would be something like

```
 findOne(HEROES, {id :1 }) => id:1, name: 'Captain America', squad: 'Avengers' }
```

I already tried making a for loop that checked if query.id was equal to the arr[i].id , and etc etc for each case, but I couldn't get it to work so that if the input was two queries, like id: 4 and squad: 'Justice League', I would not get the right result. Some would be right, but some would be wrong. Idk it's kinda hard to explain.

```
function findOne(arr, query){
  let i = 0;
   while (i<arr.length){
   if (Object.values(query) in Object.values(arr[i])){  
    return arr[i];
  }
  i++;
}
}
```

Now I've tried to make the code a lot simpler, but running into some difficulties. It seems the first test case works, but none of the others work. For example, 
     findOne(HEROES, { id: 2, name: 'Aquaman' 
should return null,

Comment: The example function call `findOne(HEROES, {id :1 }) => id:1, name: 'Captain America', squad: 'Avengers' }` is not valid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const HEROES = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Captain America', squad: 'Avengers' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Iron Man', squad: 'Avengers' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Spiderman', squad: 'Avengers' },
];


function findOne(arr, query) {

    let i = 0;
    let result = "Not Found";
    while (i < arr.length) {
         flag =0;
            for(key in query) {
                     if(query[key]!=arr[i][key]){
                         flag = 1;
                        
                     }    
            }
            if(flag == 0) {
                result = arr[i];  
                break; 
            }
        i++;
    }

    return result;

}

let result = findOne(HEROES, {id:2,name:'Iron Man'});
console.log(result);
```

This logic will work

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem here is that the queries change in fields, e.g you don't know which fields you get in the query object (if I got you right).

using `Object.values(query)` is not the best idea, since a query like this qould also pass the test and return the 1st hero: `{ id: 'Avengers', name: 1 }`.

Use `Object.keys` instead:

```
function findOne(arr, query){
  let keys = Object.keys(query);
  while(i<arr.length){
     let equalKeyCounter = 0;
     for( key in keys ){
        if(query[key] === arr[i][key])
          equalKeyCounter++;
     }
     if( equalKeyCounter == keys.length )
        return arr[i];
  }
   return "not found"; // or null , undefined, any other default value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a ES6 answer.

The code in ES6 would be something like:

```
const result = HEROES.find(hero => 
  Object.entries(query).every(([key,value]) => key in hero && hero[key] === value))
```

That basically returns the first item in the `HEROES` array that matches the props in the `query` object given. If you want to create a function, could be then:

```
const find = (items, query) => items.find(item => 
  Object.entries(query).every(([key,value]) => key in item && item[key] === value))
```

With a simple change of method, you could also have a function that returns, instead, all the items that match the query – not just the first:

```
const findAll = (items, query) => items.filters(item => 
  Object.entries(query).every(([key,value]) => key in item && item[key] === value))
```

That returns always a new array – empty if no items are matching the props of `query`.
For example, using your data:

```
   console.log(find(HEROES, {squad: 'Avengers'}));
   // { id: 1, name: 'Captain America', squad: 'Avengers' } 

   console.log(find(HEROES, {squad: 'Avengers'}));
   // [
   //   { id: 1, name: 'Captain America', squad: 'Avengers' },
   //   { id: 2, name: 'Iron Man', squad: 'Avengers' },
   //   { id: 3, name: 'Spiderman', squad: 'Avengers' },
   // ]
```

Same query, but since the second function returns all the matching items, you have multiple results.

Hope it helps!
Here you can find more about the methods used: [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), [Array#find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to Zer0, but used reduce instead. I also made the function a behave similar to mongoose findOne which returns the first matching result (btw it is TS):

```
type Hero = Record<string, any>;

export const findOne = (arr: Hero[], filter: Partial<Hero>) => arr.filter((obj) => Object.keys(filter).reduce((acc, key) => acc || obj[key] === filter[key], false)).shift();

const HEROES = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Captain America', squad: 'Avengers' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Iron Man', squad: 'Avengers' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Spiderman', squad: 'Avengers' },
];
const hero = findOne(HEROES, { squad: 'Avengers' });

console.log('The first Avenger is? ', hero);
// The first Avenger is? { id: 1, name: 'Captain America', squad: 'Avengers' },
```